# Backpropagation errors on dense-sparse matrices in PyTorch

Tags: pytorch, sparse-matrix

As PyTorch  does not (yet?) support broadcasting on sparse matrices, I implemented a simple autograd class. Forward propagation works fine, but backpropagation fails with a cryptic error:

`Could not run 'aten::as_strided' with arguments from the 'SparseCPU' backend.`

[Here](https://gist.github.com/mino98/38ef8278470ffdd254c50b428cf1bb38) is a snippet of minimal code to reproduce the issue:

```py
import torch
from torch.autograd import Function

# creating this custom autograd function in order to handle broadcasting in sparse matrices
# as described below

class BroadcastSparse1D(Function):
    @staticmethod
    def forward(ctx, sparse_1d, target_shape):
        assert sparse_1d.dim() == 1, "Input tensor must be 1-dimensional"
        
        target_dims = len(target_shape)
        
        new_indices = torch.zeros(target_dims, sparse_1d._nnz())
        new_indices[0, :] = sparse_1d._indices()[0, :]
        
        broadcasted_sparse = torch.sparse_coo_tensor(new_indices, sparse_1d._values(), target_shape, device=sparse_1d.device)

        ctx.save_for_backward(sparse_1d)
        ctx.target_shape = target_shape
        
        return broadcasted_sparse

    @staticmethod
    def backward(ctx, grad_output):
        sparse_1d, = ctx.saved_tensors

        # Convert grad_output to dense and sum over the required dimensions
        grad_output_dense = grad_output.to_dense()
        grad_sum_dense = grad_output_dense.sum(dim=tuple(range(1, len(ctx.target_shape))))

        # Convert the dense gradient sum back to a sparse tensor
        grad_sum_sparse = grad_sum_dense.to_sparse()
        
        grad_input = torch.sparse_coo_tensor(sparse_1d._indices(), grad_sum_sparse._values(), sparse_1d.shape, device=grad_output.device)
        return grad_input, None

broadcast_sparse_1d = BroadcastSparse1D.apply

# mocking up the input parameters:
#
# as you can see I am tracking gradients for `a` and `c`.
# also, note that `c` and `d` are sparse tensors.

a = torch.rand((4, 4, 176))
a.requires_grad_(True)

b = torch.rand((64, 64))

c = torch.rand((64, 64, 184)).to_sparse()
c.requires_grad_(True)

d = torch.rand((184, 4, 4, 176)).to_sparse()

# this is the chain of forward calculations

e = torch.sum(b.unsqueeze(-1) * c, dim=(0, 1))

e_broadcasted = broadcast_sparse_1d(e, d.shape) # we use this to emulate broadcasting, since `e` is 
                                                # of shape (184) and `d` of shape (184, 4, 4, 176)

f = torch.sum(e_broadcasted * d, dim=0)
result =  -torch.min((a * 400) - f)
```

Am I doing something obviously silly?

Comment: Re *"a snippet of minimal code...<URL>"*: Likely a faux pas

Comment: You know, when I ran your code I got a shape related error before I even hit the error you're describing. Maybe try restarting your kernel? https://pastebin.com/dXUMqAf7

Comment: Also if this is useful, this indicates that it should be implemented: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/45996

Comment: @BrockBrown: I just double checked, and I don't get your error in a fresh colab.